# Increment issues

Tags: javascript, html

I have a timer going that adds 1 every second to the variable `MenuTimer`. 
What I want is when the next button is pressed `TillOpen` The `MenuTimer` will stop having 1 added to it after that and a new variable to have 1 added instead `PackTime`

```
window.onload = function () {
    var StopwatchSeconds= 00;
    var StopwatchMinutes = 00;
    var ShowSeconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
    var ShowMinutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
    var StartButton = document.getElementById("ButtonStart");
    var Interval;
    var menuTime;
    var serviceTime;
    var orders;
    var menuAvg;
    var serviceAvg;

    StartButton.onclick= function(){
        clearInterval(Interval);
        Interval = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
    }

    function startTimer () {
        StopwatchSeconds++;

        if(StopwatchSeconds > 59) {

            ShowSeconds.innerHTML = "0" + StopwatchSeconds; 
            StopwatchSeconds = 0; 
            ShowMinutes.innerHTML = StopwatchMinutes;
            StopwatchMinutes++;
        }

        if(StopwatchSeconds < 59) {
            ShowSeconds.innerHTML = StopwatchSeconds;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your code do, and what's the problem?

Comment: The plan is for the code to time How long "Menu" and "Till Open" take. And once i've got the times for that to also be able to show the average of both as well as the average of both put together. 
eg. Menu has 10s, 40s and 20s. Till open has 5s, 10s and 30s. So we can get Menu's average and Till open average BUT also the average of both put together. eg 10 + 5s, 40+ 10s and 20 + 30s.

Answer (score 0):

New solution, wich allows to create different timers and keep track of them:

```
//a method to setup a new timer
function Timer(Name){
   this.timeElement=document.createElement("div");
   (this.stopButton=document.createElement("button")).innerHTML="STOP";
   (this.startButton=document.createElement("button")).innerHTML="START";
   (this.Name=document.createElement("h1")).innerHTML=Name;
   [this.Name,this.timeElement,this.startButton,this.stopButton].forEach(el=>document.body.appendChild(el));

   this.stopButton.addEventListener("click",this.stop.bind(this));
   this.startButton.addEventListener("click",this.start.bind(this));

   this.seconds=0;
   this.minutes=0;
}

Timer.prototype={

    update:function() {
        this.seconds++;
        if(this.seconds > 59) {
             this.seconds=0;
             this.minutes++;
        }
        var secTemp="00"+this.seconds, minTemp="00"+this.minutes;
        this.timeElement.innerHTML=minTemp.slice(minTemp.length-2)+":"+secTemp.slice(secTemp.length-2);
    },     


    stop:function(){
         if(this.interval) clearInterval(this.interval);
         this.running=false;
         if(this.onstop) this.onstop(this);
    }   

    start:function(){
         if(this.interval) clearInterval(this.interval);
         this.interval = setInterval(this.update.bind(this), 1000);
         this.running=true;
         if(this.onstart) this.onstart(this);             
    }   
};
```

This implements a Timer with OOP. So you can create multiple timers, and they wont influence each other.

You can create a timer like this:

```
var timer= new Timer("The Name");
```

You can also change events, set/read the times and check if running:

```
timer.start();//start the timer ( can also be done with the ui button)
timer.stop();
timer.onstart=()=>alert("Started!");
timer.onstop=()=>alert("Stopped!");
console.log(timer.running,timer.minutes,timer.seconds);
```

If you want to wait for multiple timers and to calculate the average if all of them stopped:

```
var timers=["Timer 1", "Timer 2"].map(name=>new Timer(name));//create two timers and store in array
timers.forEach(function(timer){
   timer.running=true;
   timer.onstop=function(){
      if(timers.some(t=>t.running)) return;//if theres a running timer dont procceed

      var seconds=timers.reduce((seconds,timer)=>seconds+=(timer.seconds+timer.minutes*60),0);
      var average=seconds/timers.length;
      alert("Average: "+average+"s");
  };
});
```

http://jsbin.com/coduvohewu/edit?output

The old solution, adding a timer if the new button is pressed, and stops the old one then:

So you want to stop the current timer, and create a new one below that? Maybe you could refactor the code a bit, doing sth like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
var seconds= 0,minutes = 0;
var times=[];
var Interval;
var timeElement;

//a method to setup a new timer
function createTimer(dontsave){
   if(times.length>3) return alert(times.map(el=>el.join(":")).join());
   timeElement=document.createElement("div");
   document.body.appendChild(timeElement);
   if(!dontsave) times.push([minutes,seconds]);
}

createTimer(true);

//a method to let the timer run
function startTimer () {
    seconds++;
    if(seconds > 59) {
       seconds=0;
       minutes++;
    }
    var secTemp="00"+seconds,minTemp="00"+minutes;
    timeElement.innerHTML=minTemp.slice(minTemp.length-2)+":"+secTemp.slice(secTemp.length-2);
}     

//assign to buttons:

document.getElementById("ButtonStart").onclick= function(){
 clearInterval(Interval);
 Interval = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
}

document.getElementById("ButtonNew").onclick=createTimer;

};
```

http://jsbin.com/mujisaweyo/edit?output

This simply creates a new div in the DOM if you press a button with the id *ButtonNew* . So the current time stays as a text in the old Element, and it keeps counting in the new one. Ive also added a zero filling...

Comment: Oh thats actually awesome. The problem is 3 timers xD or at least 3 variables to hold the timers in, if that makes sense. So I want one Timer to time "Menu" and another to time "Till Open". But AFTER that I need to get the averages of both. As well as the Average total time.

Comment: @user3500310 ive added a few lines to store the values in an array. However, i think your task needs a bit different approach. I will work on it...

Comment: This has been really helpful. Thank you so much! Ill keep working on it as well and see if I can get it to work. Or should I try look for a new approach?

Comment: @user3500310 youre welcome ;) i think the upper solution is the best in this case ( i think). If it was really helpful, you can express that through giving an upvote or marking as answer ;)

Comment: Hey Jonas im a little confused. I need the timer to restart rather than continue while adding?

Answer (score 0):

Here's all of it. It half works but hopefully you get a better Idea of what i'm trying to go for.

```
var Interval;
var PackInterval;
var StopwatchSeconds= 00;
var StopwatchMinutes = 00;
var ShowSeconds = document.getElementById("seconds");
var ShowMinutes = document.getElementById("minutes");
var StartButton = document.getElementById("ButtonStart");
var TillOpenButton = document.getElementById("TillOpen");
var FinishButton = document.getElementById("Finish");
var ShowMenuTime = document.getElementById("MenuTime");
var ShowPackTime = document.getElementById("PackTime");
var ShowPackAvgSeconds = document.getElementById("PackerSeconds");
var ShowPackAvgMinutes = document.getElementById("PackerMinutes");
var ShowMenuAvgSeconds = document.getElementById("MenuMinutes");
var ShowMenuAvgMinutes = document.getElementById("MenuSeconds");
var DivisionSeconds = 60;
var TotalTime = 0;
var MenuTime = 0;
var PackTime = 0;
var AllMenuTimes = 0;
var AllPackTimes = 0;
var TotalMenuOrders = 0;
var TotalPackOrders = 0;
var MenuOrdersTotalSeconds = 0;
var PackOrdersTotalSeconds = 0;
var MenuAvgMinutes = 0;
var MenuAvgSeconds = 0;
var PackAvgSeconds = 0;
var PackAvgMinutes = 0;



StartButton.onclick = function(){
  TotalMenuOrders + 1;
  MenuTime = 0;
  ShowMenuTime.innerHTML = MenuTime; 
  clearInterval(Interval);
  Interval = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);

  window.alert ("I work");


 }

//This starts the timer. Inverval is a variable that holds the timer number. 

function startTimer () {

    StopwatchSeconds++;
    TotalTime++;
    MenuTime++; 
   AllMenuTime++;
    if(StopwatchSeconds > 59) {

        ShowSeconds.innerHTML = "0" + StopwatchSeconds; 
      StopwatchSeconds = 0; 

            StopwatchMinutes++;
      ShowMinutes.innerHTML = StopwatchMinutes; // Makes this a string in html

    }

    if(StopwatchSeconds < 59) {
        ShowSeconds.innerHTML = StopwatchSeconds;
     }
}

// When the start button is pressed this function starts. it adds 1 to 
Stopwatch, total and Menu every 1000 increments that Interval hits. 
// This also says if StopwatchSeconds goes above 59 itll reset to 0 and if 
its below itll keep counting. 

TillOpenButton.onclick = function () {
    PackTime = 0;
   ShowPackTime.innerHTML = PackTime;
      ShowMenuTime.innerHTML = MenuTime;
    PackInterval = setInterval(startPackerTimer, 1000);
         Interval+PackInterval;
      clearInterval(Interval);


/*    if (TotalMenuOrders < 1) {

  AllMenuTimes / TotalMenuOrders = MenuOrdersTotalSeconds;
 MenuOrderTotalSeconds % 60 = MenuAvgSeconds;
  MenuAvgMinutes = Math.floor(MenuOrderTotalSeconds/60);

  ShowMenuAvgMinutes.innerHTML = MenuAvgMinutes; 
  ShowMenuAvgSeconds.innerHTML = MenuAvgSeconds;
  }
  */
    }






// When this button is pressed it stops the first timer and the menu timer. 
It then starts a new timer and function which add to the variable that will 
show the total time. 
// It does clear the variable Interval though

FinishButton.onclick = function (){
  clearInterval(Interval);
  ShowPackTime.innerHTML = PackTime;
  clearInterval(PackInterval);
  StopwatchSeconds = 0;
  StopwatchMinutes = 0;
  ShowSeconds.innerHTMl = 0 + StopwatchSeconds; 
  ShowMinutes.innerHTML = 0 + StopwatchMinutes;

  AllPackTimes += PackTime;
  TotalPackOrders++;

   /*AllPackTimes/TotalPackOrders = PackOrderTotalSeconds;
     PackOrderTotalSeconds % DivisionSeconds = PackAvgSeconds;

  PackAvgMinutes = Math.floor(PackOrderTotalSeconds/60);

  ShowPackAvgMinutes.innerHTML = PackAvgMinutes; 
  ShowPackAvgSeconds.innerHTML = PackAvgSeconds;*/


}

// When the Finish Button is pressed it clears everything. Resets 
everything. except Menu Time, Total Time and PackTime. I need 3 new 
variables to hold these to get the average. 






function startPackerTimer () {

  StopwatchSeconds++;
    TotalTime++;
    PackTime++;

    if(StopwatchSeconds > 59) {

        ShowSeconds.innerHTML = "0" + StopwatchSeconds; 
      StopwatchSeconds = 0; 

        StopwatchMinutes++;
      ShowMinutes.innerHTML = StopwatchMinutes;

    }

    if(StopwatchSeconds < 59) {
        ShowSeconds.innerHTML = StopwatchSeconds;
    }
    // Same deal but with the Till open button. Still adds onto 
STopwatchSeconds so the variable doesn't change.
```

}